# How to get the rank of an element in vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I need to get the rank (the positional index+1) of an element for containers in C++ like `vector` or `list`. Is there a convenient way of doing so? I could have done testing based on `nth_element` in order to find the rank. Or I could sort and do binary search to find the rank. But all of these do not seem very efficient in the worst-case. I'd like to get O(lgn) complexity, and done with STL algorithms if possible.

Comment: If you want better than scanning the container, then you picked the wrong container. At the very least, there's no _catch-all_ approach that'll be optimal for every container type.

Comment: Ummm... use the already available method for finding an item's index and add 1?  How do you think this could be achieved in a collection like a vector without potentially looking at each item?  Is this actually a performance problem?  I would have to assume that, if you have proven that it is, you would have then come to the conclusion that you are using the wrong data structure for the job.

Comment: @EdS.: "Q: What is the method?" "A: Use the method." Hmm.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Read past the first sentence.  Also, using google for the most simple of stl operations is tough, right?

Comment: @EdS: (a) it wasn't there when I wrote; (b) it doesn't change anything :)

Comment: @EdS.: Slightly more so than for Standard Library operations.

Comment: If you need to get a rank of a C++ element in a container in better than `O(n)`, you should use `std::set`  instead of `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Comment: It's not possible unless you've sorted the container or otherwise imposed some kind of structure you can use. Sketch proof: suppose that the desired element could be anywhere, and that examining an element that is not the desired element tells you nothing about the location of the target. Then whatever order you examine the elements, there are inputs for which the target will be the nth place you look. Hence in the worst case performance is Omega(n).

Answer (score 5):

If your container has random access iterators (e.g. vector) and is sorted, you can use the `std::lower_bound()` algorithm to get an elements index in O(log n) complexity. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v({10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20});
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
auto iter = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 20);
std::cout << "index " << int(iter - v.begin()) << std::endl;
```

(I'm using C++11 syntax to keep the code short, but you should get the idea).

Note that you can insert elements to a vector in a sorted way, so you don't need to sort before finding the index.

Comment: At the very least you should assert sortedness before running this algorithm.

Comment: At the very least you should read to the end of the answer you comment on ♥

Comment: In my example code I'm sorting before running the algorithm just to show its use, of course doing that is *worse* than just linear search. As I noted, you should keep your `vector` sorted when inserting, and that's the better use case for this algorithm (You get O(log n) insertion and O(log n) search, as opposed to O(1) insertion and O(n) search.)

Comment: @spatz: if you keep the vector sorted when inserting then you get O(n) insertion, it's not O(log n). First find the insertion point using approx `log n` comparisons, then shuffle everything to the right of it along one space to make a gap (expected `n/2` copies/moves).

Comment: @SteveJessop, you're right. Keeping the vector sorted gives O(n) insertion and O(log n) search. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It seems very unlikely that you will find something more efficient than linear search here. The worst case must necessarily be that you compare all elements with what you search for - and that is exactly what linear search gives you.

Answer (score 0):

this might be abit untidy.

you can use the fact that elements in vectors are contiguous within memory.

so what you have to do is

1) get the iterator address of the element of interest

2) subtract with the vector.begin() to get the total memory

3) divide by the size of one element

this should give you the position (or rank).

this is assuming that the elements are fixed size.

Comment: (a) the assumption that the OP has an actual instance that is already stored within the vector is not suggested in the post, so probably not true. (b) if they *did*, they could just subtract the two iterators; there would be no point in adding an additional layer of complication and error-prone-ness by layering pointers over that too, **and** that would work with containers that do not have to be contiguous in memory (albeit better to use `std::distance()` than to subtract).